# combine two array in javascript if id is the same, pick the one on 2th array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to combine two array together with **lodash** but there is a catch. If item has the same id, pick the one from the 2th array instead.
Example:

```
let arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1'}, { id: 2, name: 'name2'}, { id: 3, name: 'name3'}];
let arr2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'name3', score: 1}];
```

Expected result

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'name1'}, { id: 2, name: 'name2'}, { id: 3, name: 'name3', score: 1}];
```

Any idea, how to achieve that. Shoot me some idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given `javascript` at Question how would you know the difference? `score` property? What have you tried to resolve inquiry?

Comment: @guest271314 There is only one difference which is 2th array will have one more field in each object. If I join them together and id of object from each array is the same, then I want to take the one that has score field.

Comment: `var res = Object.assign([], arr1, arr2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check if an item of the second array exist, then take the one from the second otherwise from the first array.

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1'}, { id: 2, name: 'name2'}, { id: 3, name: 'name3'}],
    array2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'name3', score: 1}],
    map2 = new Map(array2.map(a => [a.id, a])),
    result = array1.map(a => map2.get(a.id) || a);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5 with an object as hash table.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1'}, { id: 2, name: 'name2'}, { id: 3, name: 'name3'}],
    array2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'name3', score: 1}],
    map2 = array2.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.id] = a;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)),
    result = array1.map(function (a) {
        return map2[a.id] || a;
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```